# VBScript - Database - Recordset - How to pass DateDiff value in the database

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, sql-server-2000

I'm using DateDiff() function of ASP to find the date difference between two dates.

The Function works fine and displays the exact date difference between two dates but when it comes to insert this value in the database it takes 9 as the value irrespect of any date difference.

Suppose difference between two dates is more than 15 or 20 days, in the database it takes "9".

I have used INT as the DATA TYPE for the column where it displaying the date difference.

Is DATA TYPE creating an issue here?
I even tried using session variable to store the value but no luck - here's my code below:

```vb
if request.Form("sub") <> "" then
        sql = "Select * from emp_leave_details"
        rs.open sql , con, 1, 2
        dim diff
        dim todate
        dim fromdate            
        fromdate= rs("leave_from")
        todate= rs("leave_to")
        session("date_diff")=datediff("d",fromdate,todate)
        rs.addnew



        rs("emp_name") = request.Form("name")
        rs("emp_no") = request.Form("number")
        rs("address") = request.Form("address")
        rs("contact_no") = request.Form("contact")
        rs("mobile_no") = request.Form("mobile")
        rs("contact_onleave") = request.Form("contact_details")
        rs("leave_type") = request.Form("rad")
        rs("other_leave_details") = request.Form("PS")
        rs("leave_from") = request.Form("from")
        rs("leave_to") = request.Form("to")
        rs("applied_by") = request.Form("apply")
        rs("accepted_by") = request.Form("accept")
        rs("approved_by") = request.Form("approve")
        rs("no_of_leave_taken")= session("date_diff")
        rs.update

        response.Write("<script language='javascript'>{update();}</script>")

        rs.close
        end if
```

Comment: You are reading `fromdate`and `todate` from the first RecordSet selected by `SELECT * FROM emp_leave_details` ... is this really intended? It looks like you always use them same data (as far as select * from is consistent).

Comment: @  Filburt thank you for your reply...I didn't understand what you trying to say..will you elaborate..

Comment: Now if I put my Query as this '  sql = "Select * from emp_leave_details where emp_name='"&session("Username")&"'" 'value that goes in the database is "14".....no matter what the date difference....be

Comment: when you do your query, your `leave_date` and `todate` are always taken from the first record of your dataset. Should `fromdate= rs("leave_from")` and `todate= rs("leave_to")` be `fromdate= request.form("leave_from")` and `todate= request.form("leave_to")` instead?

Comment: @oracle certified professional you are right it takes up the first record present in the dataset. I crossed checked it the first entry is having date difference of "9"...thats the reasin it was showing 9 everytime I submit a new record.....but now instead of ' fromdate=rs("leave_from") ' and ' todate=rs("leave_to") ' if I use ' request.form ' in place of rs ...value passed to the database is Zero .

Comment: Convert the `request.form` values to a date using `cDate` and then get the difference.

Comment: @Guido I tried this but no luck fromdate= cdate(request.form("leave_from"))

Comment: @GuidoGautier if i use this in my code on my page it displays exact answer that I want i.e difference is perfect....so y is the database not taking up this value and taking zero as the value

Comment: Okay, the problem is within the database then. `Int` should be the correct datatype. Try to execute the query manually from Server Management Studio or from your code using `cn.execute(QUERY)`

Comment: @Mckenzi Getting your SELECT query right is the way to go. Try debugging your SELECT query by testing it directly against your database. Also try to `Response.Write` your SELECT query to make sure there is no mixup in the quotes around the employee username.

Comment: @Filburt The select query is misleading, OP meant to use the `Request.Form` collection. See @oraclecertifiedprofessional and reply after that from OP.

Answer (score 1):

The datatype has nothing to do with this. Storing the value in the session is not the solution. You can use a regular variable.

From your code it looks like you always use the same values for `fromdate` and `todate`. This is because you do not iterate the rows in the resultset.

```
if not rs.bof and not rs.eof then
    do while not rs.eof

        '' code to execute for each row            

        rs.moveNext
    loop
end if
```

In your current script `rs` will always return the results of the first row returned by the query.

The second problem your running into might be the `Date` datatype. Convert your value to a date using `cDate` and use this to calculate the difference.

Comment: I doubt that iterating over all records is what the OP is looking for - it seems rather that he tries to create a new record for the currently logged in user/employee.

Comment: This became clear after comments from OP. At first, this seemed to be the problem and based on OP's code this is still part of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is , you search for "Select * from emp_leave_details" which always gives all records from that table. You retrieve the values of the first record and do a diff of these, which results in always the same value, that is normal. From your question it is unclear what you really want to do. I suppose so want so select a record like

```
Select * from emp_leave_details where emp_name=<%=request.Form("name")%>
```

and based on that add a new record with a computed no_of_leave_taken.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys my bad...
It was the database field name that I was calling instead of

```
fromdate= request.form("from")
todate= request.form("to")
```

I was calling this

```
fromdate= request.form("leave_from")
todate= request.form("leave_to")
```

Sorry again..but I really appreciate you all for providing me with all that possible solutions.

Thanks.